# Are there Nuclear Weapons in Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

In *Rogue One*, destruction caused by single laser fire of Death Star looked similar to nuclear weapon destruction. But, seeing it was given such a big focus (even Empire was showing it off to create fear), I wondered whether there're nuclear weapons in Star Wars universe.

Also, I see TIE fighters and X-wings always have low yield bombardments. Our real world fighter jets (having nuclear warheads) could do better to destroy *Thermal Oscillator* on *Starkiller*.

Does Star Wars universe have nuclear weapons or other mass destruction weapons having similar yield (of course, excluding Death Star and Starkiller)?